# Wireless Network Connection gets dropped at times under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have running Windows 7 on my hp laptop with 802.11n wifi adapter.
Some times, I lost wireless internet connection. Under the 'Wireless Connection' when I click the notification area, it said 'my home network is 'connected'... But in the header 'currently  Connected to' it said 'no internet access' instead of 'internet access'

I can 'fix' my problem by going to the 'wireless connection' my home network, click 'disconnect' and then click 'connect'.  And when it comes back up, it gets connected again.

any idea how can i fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the connection become more stable when you take your laptop right next to your access point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest, is to check that there's no interference for your wireless network.

My neighbour flew radio controlled helicopters, and they used the 2.6Ghz frequency range, which caused a drop out on wireless networks.

It may also be worth changing the wireless channel, on your router, to see if that helps?

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This could also be your wireless router losing signal from your ISP. Easiest to diagnose if you have 2 computers losing Internet connection while still 'connected' to the router.